# Anyone with any experience using compliance recording solutions with Microsoft Teams to record PSTN calls?

Tags: recording, microsoft-teams

I am working with a small Health Insurance broker that is using Teams. They are considering migrating their phone numbers into Teams and are further interested in having PSTN calls to these Teams numbers recorded. Calls related to Medicare/Medicaid need to be recorded for compliance purposes.

I know that they can manually start a recording for meetings occurring within the Teams client and the appropriate policy changes set, but recordings are not currently supported for PSTN calls without the use of a partner - MS lists a bunch on their website.

Does anyone have any experience with any MS partners for this scenario? I do plan on calling around and getting demos. This broker would like, for example, inbound PSTN calls to a specific team's number to be automatically recorded.

Partners are listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-recording-policy#compliance-recording-for-teams-certification-programs

Comment: If you have a specific question regarding this we MAY be able to answer, but just asking if we have experience doesn't give us a question that is on topic here.